# Getting an Unexpected Token error trying to execute a transaction (Tenderly simulation works fine)

Tags: gnosis-safe, error

Getting this error trying to execute a transaction on the gnosis.

{"code":-32603,"message":"Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON","data":{"originalError":{}}}

Tenderly link if helpful: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/0cf92095-613a-4f4e-9ca8-f17dff118e4a

Please let me know if I can provide any additional info

Thanks so much

[image: Error]

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for your experience - this is definitely an app issue and not a question for StackOverflow. I've notified the web team, and they'll look into the issue. If you have any more questions, please feel free to contact the support team and you can reference my message

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is on the FrontEnd side of the Gnosis Safe UI because Tenderly simulator is working so it also should let you create a transaction . Ask for help from Safe Team by writing a mail or from discord

Comment: Yeah, thats what I tried at first.  unfortunately they directed me here.